# Como muestro un div y oculto varios y dejar la pagina asi?

Tags: javascript, div, spa

Aqui dejo el menu con las funciones que aplique.
No puse todos los container poque son extensos.

```
    <header class="respmen">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
            <label for="btn-menu"><img id="ham" src="./css/images/cancha.jpg" ></label>
            <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li ><a href="" onclick="showHome ()"> Home </a></li>
                <li ><a href="" onclick="showAbout ()">About NYSL</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" onclick="showReg ()">Registration</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" onclick="showGame ()">Game Information</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" onclick="showRule ()">Rules</a></li>
                <li ><a href="" onclick="showContact ()" >Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          </header>
            <div id="container">
              <div id="pageheader">
                <h1>Upcoming Events</h1>
    
              </div>  
              
              <div  id="bodycontent">
                <div id="upcoming">
                  <h3>August 4</h3>
                  <p class="indent">NYSL Fundraiser</p>
          
                  <h3>August 16</h3>
                  <p class="indent">Season Kick-off: Meet the Teams</p>
                  
                  <h3>September 1</h3>
                  <p class="indent"> First Game of the Season (Check Game Schedule for details)</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           
            
            
              <div id="container2">
                <div id="pageheader">
                  <h1>About</h1>
                </div>
                          
              
                
                <div id="bodycontent2">
                <h3>Mission</h3>
                <p class="indent">To support young athletes living in Chicago's northside neighborhoods, who have an interest in learning and playing soccer, with opportunities to learn and practice skills related to the game of soccer, specifically those skills around team cooperation and good sportsmanship.</p>
                
                <h3>Vision</h3>
                <p class="indent">The Northside Youth Soccer League aspires to develop strong, well-rounded, and mindful athletes through the building of character, self-discipline, and leadership.</p>
                
                <h3>General Information</h3>
                <p class="indent">The Northside Youth Soccer League was established in 1996 to provide athletes residing in Chicago's northside neighborhoods an environment in which to learn and play soccer. To be a member of NYSL, you must be between the ages of 4 - 12 and reside in a Chicago northside neighborhood. NYSL is run by a small full-time staff, and relies on the generous volunteer time of parents and previous league members.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
```

1-Aqui dejo lo que aplique.
El problema es que esconde los div y muestra el que quiero, solo que los muestra rapido y los esconde de nuevo, lo que quiero es que deje fijado el div seleccionado.
en el css tengo con display none todos menos el home.

```
function showHome () { 
 document.getElementById("container").style.display="block"
 document.getElementById("container2").style.display="none"
 document.getElementById("container3").style.display="none" 
 document.getElementById("container4").style.display="none"
 document.getElementById("container5").style.display="none"
 document.getElementById("container6").style.display="none" 

}
```

esto aplique y me lo muestra y desaparece

Comment: Dos problemas, intentas recuperar varios elementos mediante IDs que no están en la página, no en el código que has puesto al menos, pero el principal: tienes que cancelar el evento de los *anchor* para usar un clic sobre ellos dentro de la misma página.

Comment: Si me falto subir una parte pero es mi primer post y me costo subirlo disculpen, para cancelar el anchor que deberia agregarle ?

Comment: En lugar de usar una función para cada enlace deberias usar la misma pasandole un valor que se corresponda con el id del div que quieres mantener abierto, y cerrar todos los demas. Eso lo puedes hacer con querySelectorAll() y en el selector pones el cacho de cadena a buscar para que coja todos o bien usa una misma clase para todos, y luego muestras el que quieres mostrar con su id.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda pude solucionarlo :) .

Answer (score 0):

No es buena idea acceder a cada contenedor por solo ID, porque te obliga a crear variables o funciones para cada uno. Aparte de ID, puedes agregar una clase para aplicar a todos el mismo estilo y agregar otra para que sea el que se muestre.

```
<div id="identificador1" class="container active"></div>
<div id="identificador2" class="container"></div>
<div id="identificador3" class="container"></div>
<div id="identificador4" class="container"></div>
<div id="identificador5" class="container"></div>
```

En CSS defines la clase `container` con `display: none;` para que no se muestren y solo a uno, el que quieras que aparezca al cargar la página, le agregas `active` para mostrarlo.

Para asociar enlaces con contenedores, asigna el atributo `href` con el selector CSS que corresponda:

```
<!-- El enlace -->
<a href="#about">Acerca del Juego</a>

<!-- El contenedor -->
<div id="about" class="container">Aquí el texto</div>
```

Cuando se hace clic en el enlace, se toma el atributo `href` y, automáticamente, queda el selector CSS para usar con `document.querySelector()` y acceder al contenedor por ID, en este caso `#about`

Esto ayuda a simplificar la lógica, agrupando los contenedores en una variable y usando solo una función mara mostrar u ocultar. Revisa los comentarios en el código para saber lo que se hace en cada paso.

```js
// Obtener todos los contenedores
let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');

// Función para mostrar solo el que corresponde al enlace y ocultar los demás
function showContainer(link) {
    // Ocultar todos los contenedores
    containers.forEach(container => container.classList.remove('active'));
    // Obtener ID a buscar
    let selector = link.getAttribute('href');
    // Buscar contenedor
    let container = document.querySelector(selector);
    // Solo si existe
    if(container) {
        // Agregar clase para mostrar
        container.classList.add('active');
    }
}

// Escuchar clics en la barra de navegación
document.querySelector('.respmen .menu').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // e.target es el elemento que recibió clic
    // Asegurar que se trata de un enlace
    if(e.target.tagName == 'A') {
        // Ejecutar función para mostrar enviando el enlace como parámetro
        showContainer(e.target);
    }
});
```

```css
/* Ocultar todos los elementos con esta clase */
.container {
    display: none;
}
/* Mostrar solo el que tenga la clase active */
.container.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="respmen">
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
    <label for="btn-menu"><img id="ham" src="./css/images/cancha.jpg" ></label>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About NYSL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#registration">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#game">Game Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- Cada contenedor debe tener ID y clase, solo uno activo -->
<div id="home" class="container active">
    <div class="pageheader">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="about" class="container">
    <div class="pageheader">
        <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="rules" class="container">
    <div class="pageheader">
        <h1>Rules</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo no hay un contenedor para cada enlace, por lo que si haces clic en `contact` se van a ocultar todos. Ya depende de ti hacerlo completo.

**Nota final:** En cada contenedor repites `<div id="pagheader">`, pero los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), es mejor cambiar a clase. Gracias a @Orici por la observación.

Comment: Has repetido el ID `id="pageheader"` lo que no se debe hacer, como ***un identificador dentro de un docuento HTML debe ser único***, supongo que querías usar una clase en su lugar.

Comment: @Orici, cierto, pasé por alto ese detalle y ya lo corregí. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos, pude solucionarlo y  me lo explicaron de manera muy didactica, excelente comunidad realmente.